# Onkeypress number validation from 1 to 10

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in validating a textbox using onkeypress. I need to allow textbox to accept only numbers from 1 to 10. I have a part of code to accept only numbers but should accept only numbers from 1 to 10. I need to restrict numbers greater than 10. Please help me in solving this.

```js
function digitKeyOnly(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
  if ((keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) || (keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13) || (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input class="text" name="Serial_Num" type="text" id="SrNo" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return digitKeyOnly(event)" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems hacky, but does the trick:

```js
function digitKeyOnly(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
  var value = Number(e.target.value + e.key) || 0;

  if ((keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) || (keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13) || (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)) {
    return isValidNumber(value);
  }
  return false;
}

function isValidNumber (number) {
  return (1 <= number && number <= 10 )
}
```

```html
<input class="text" name="Serial_Num" type="text" id="SrNo" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return digitKeyOnly(event)" />
```

Comment: You basically took my answer and wrote the script for him.

Comment: @Sparky, yes, I did.

Comment: Thank you it works...I just made some modification for accepting backspace

Comment: @streletss I have accepted your answer and it resolved my problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be that you turn the entry in the texbox into a number and then just:

```
if (1 <= number && number <= 10 ) {
    true;
}
```

Comment: @RaviPoudapelly What do you mean? Your input allows a number with 2 digits?

Comment: It allows two digits but Iam not able to read both the digits together. I could only any one single character

Comment: And why is that? If you get the value of the input, you don't need the keyCode. The only thing you need to do is restrict the input on the input tag itself to type="number". From there you can use the number in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input type as number to overcome this problem and get the number using DOM in javascript

```css
input {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .8rem;
}

input:invalid + span:after {
    content: '✖';
    color: #f00;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

input:valid + span:after {
    content: '✓';
    color: #26b72b;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="eyes" name="eyes"
           placeholder="Min: 10, max: 100"
           min="1" max="10" />
    <span class="validity"></span>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but I want to restrict number > 10 on keypress

Answer (score 0):

according to  streletss  answer and based on MaxLength attribute the codes will rewrite as below:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return digitKeyOnly(event,this)">


function digitKeyOnly(e,eln) {       
    var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    var value = Number(e.target.value + e.key) || 0;       
    if ((keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) || (keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13) || (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)) {
        return isValidNumber(value, eln.maxLength);
    }
    return false;
}

function isValidNumber(number, len) {
    return number.toString().length <= len ? true : false;       
}
```